# How to get ajax querystring from JavaScript given data object?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

When you make an AJAX request using jQuery, you can specify the data property that will be passed to the server.  If the data contains an array of objects it passes it to the server in a format something like this:

```
MyArray[0][MyPropertyA]=123&MyArray[1][MyPropertyA]=456
```

Is there a way to get the query string it will generate for the AJAX request without actually doing the AJAX request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery [param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) is your friend.

From the jQuery Param page:

> Create a serialized representation of an array or object, suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request.

Comment: Awesome.  I was hoping there was something like this.